# Fetching data from cloud firestore and rendering into html component

Tags: angular

I am fetching data from my cloud firestore and rendering in my html component.On my first attempt when i go the component i see my data rendered into html component

.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemsService } from 'src/app/services/items.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductsService } from 'src/app/services/products.service';
import { Product } from 'src/app/modals/products.modal';

@Component({
selector: 'app-admin-new',
templateUrl: './admin-new.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./admin-new.component.scss']
})
export class AdminNewComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('f') form:NgForm
categories
default="Bread"
constructor(public iservice:ItemsService,private 
prservice:ProductsService,private router:Router,private 
route:ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.iservice.getitems().subscribe(items=>{
  console.log(items)   //this is the data fetched from firestore
  this.categories=items

})
}
onsubmit(f){
this.prservice.fetchintocardcomponent(f)
this.router.navigate(['admin/products'])
}

}
```

service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 
{AngularFirestoreDocument,AngularFirestore,AngularFirestoreCollection} 
from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItemsService {
itemscollection:AngularFirestoreCollection<any>
items:Observable<any[]>

constructor(public afs:AngularFirestore,db:AngularFirestore) { 

this.items=this.afs.collection('categories',ref=>ref.orderBy('name'))
.valueChanges()  

}

getitems(){
  return this.items
}

}
```

Now i render it in html component by

```
 <select [ngModel]="default" class="browser-default custom-select" 
 id="category"
 ngModel name="select" required #select="ngModel"
  >

 <option *ngFor="let c of categories" value="{{c.name}}">{{c.name}} . 
 </option>

 </select>
```

So here is the screenshot of what i am getting, it is working fine
**https://ibb.co/PFW6sR9**

But after submitting the form when i go to another component by

```
     this.router.navigate(['admin/products'])
```

And then when i return to the same component i do not see the values fetched from firestore being rendered in the html component

Here is the screenshot of my issue
**https://ibb.co/j5yNChs**

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: @varman no not anything ! , I posted the screenshot too of the console in the link

Answer (score 0):

Don't call anything within constructor until its needed it. Just call it inside a method. So when u subscribe, it will automatically trigger. The following code should work.

```
constructor(public afs:AngularFirestore,db:AngularFirestore) { 
}

getitems(){
     return this.items=this.afs.collection('categories',
            ref=>ref.orderBy('name')).valueChanges() ;
}
```